# Self compiling python script?

Tags: python

So I am designing a program that I want to be able to recompile itself from a script inside the program. Is this possible? In addition I want it to be able to recompile itself regardless if python is installed on the machine. Any insight or recommendations are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "compile"?  Python isn't a compiled language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question:

Save this to a file called "hello_world.py"

```
import os

print "hello world"
os.system("python hello_world.py")
```

Of course, python doesn't really compile.

For the second part of the question, use something like [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), etc.

Comment: perfect, by compile I meant to make it into an executable file, it looks like py2exe would work. Thanks!